# How can I prevent a chicken-and-the-egg situation with a nested Undo/Redo feature?

Tags: javascript, undo-redo

I'm implementing undo/redo functionality in a javascript project, specifically in a node-based setting; the user may, for instance, create and delete nodes.

I've started breaking down all operations that can be performed into "action" objects that can be pushed to my undo stack, each action having a "do" and an "undo" method. I've found myself ending up with nested actions, such as with the action:

```
Act('kill node',{node:myNode})
```

...whose `do()` looks something like this:

```
{
   Act('deselect node',{node:stored.nodeId});//deselect is itself an action
   //...then remove the element from DOM, etc
}
```

This pushes a new undo step onto my stack, made up of the actions `deselect node` (added inside the kill action's do() as shown), then `kill node` proper; which works out fine when undoing as working through it in reverse will first `create` the node, then `select` it.

However, following the same order of operations with node creation turns out to be a headache, ie.:

```
Act('create node',{data:serializedString})
```

...whose `do()` is the following:

```
{
   //create the new node from the data given, and then...
   Act('select node',{node:newNodeId});
}
```

Following the same order as above, this means my stack now has the actions `select node`, then `create node`; this yields an error when performing an undo/redo as I am trying to select the node before creating it.

Reversing the way things are executed (ie. adding the original action to the stack and then any sub-actions that may arise) fixes the issue for `create node`, but breaks the `kill node` action as its effective actions are now reversed.

This issue doesn't seem to come up obviously when looking up popular undo/redo patterns and I am unsure what would be the "industry-standard" way to proceed. A possible solution would be adding "add this action after its constituents" flags on a case-by-case basis but intuitively I feel like this would make a huge mess. Another solution would be to completely avoid calling actions inside other actions, but this strikes me as a very forbidding architecture.

Is there a way to solve this at all without either of those?

**note:** here's a minimal working demo - for the sake of example, steps and actions are the same thing, so killing a node will add both a "deselect" and a "kill" step

```js
let nodeI=0;
let Node=function(fromStr)
{
  let el=document.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('node');
  el.innerHTML='Node '+nodeI+'<br>';
  document.getElementById('nodes').appendChild(el);
  el.onclick=()=>{
    if (!this.selected) Act('select',{id:this.id});
    else Act('deselect',{id:this.id});
  };
  el.node=this;
  this.el=el;
  this.id=nodeI;
  if (fromStr)
  {
    fromStr=JSON.parse(fromStr);
    for (var i in fromStr){this[i]=fromStr[i];}
  }
  this.el.id='node-'+this.id;
  let btn=document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML='[kill]';
  el.appendChild(btn);
  btn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.stopPropagation();
    Act('kill node',{id:this.id,fromStr:this.serialize()});
  });
  this.selected=false;
  nodeI++;
}
Node.prototype.serialize=function()
{
  return JSON.stringify({id:this.id});
}


let ActionTypes={};
let ActionType=function(id,o)
{
  this.id=id;
  for (var i in o){this[i]=o[i];}
  ActionTypes[id]=this;
}

new ActionType('create node',{
  do:stored=>{
    let node=new Node(stored.fromStr||0);
    stored.fromStr=node.serialize();
    stored.id=node.id;
    Act('select',{id:stored.id});
  },undo:stored=>{
    Act('deselect',{id:stored.id});
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).remove();
  }});
new ActionType('kill node',{
  do:stored=>{
    Act('deselect',{id:stored.id});
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).remove();
  },undo:stored=>{
    let node=new Node(stored.fromStr);
    Act('select',{id:stored.id});
  }});
new ActionType('select',{
  do:stored=>{
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).node.selected=true;
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).classList.add('selected');
  },undo:stored=>{
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).node.selected=false;
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).classList.remove('selected');
  }});
new ActionType('deselect',{
  do:stored=>{
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).node.selected=false;
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).classList.remove('selected');
  },undo:stored=>{
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).node.selected=true;
    document.getElementById('node-'+stored.id).classList.add('selected');
  }});

let undoSteps=[];
let redoSteps=[];

let inUndoRedo=false;

let updateQueueDisplay=function(){document.getElementById('queue').innerHTML='Undo: '+undoSteps.map(a=>'['+a.type.id+']').join(', ')+'<br>Redo: '+redoSteps.map(a=>'['+a.type.id+']').join(', ');}

let Undo=function()
{
  if (undoSteps.length==0) return;
  inUndoRedo=true;
  let step=undoSteps[0];
  undoSteps.shift();
  redoSteps.unshift(step);
  step.undo();
  updateQueueDisplay();
  inUndoRedo=false;
}
let Redo=function()
{
  if (redoSteps.length==0) return;
  inUndoRedo=true;
  let step=redoSteps[0];
  redoSteps.shift();
  undoSteps.unshift(step);
  step.do();
  updateQueueDisplay();
  inUndoRedo=false;
}

let Action=function(id,data){
  this.type=ActionTypes[id];
  this.stored=data||{};
};
Action.prototype.do=function()
{
  this.type.do(this.stored);
}
Action.prototype.undo=function()
{
  this.type.undo(this.stored);
}


//this variable lets us switch from one order of operation to the other.
//notice how "false" causes errors when undoing creating nodes, while "true" causes errors when undoing killing nodes.
let ReverseOrder=false;

let Act=function(id,data){
  let action=new Action(id,data);
  
  if (!ReverseOrder)//execute the action first, which adds its sub-actions before itself
  {
    action.do();
    if (!inUndoRedo)
    {
      redoSteps=[];
      undoSteps.unshift(action);
    }
  }
  else//execute the action after, which adds its sub-actions after itself
  {
    if (!inUndoRedo)
    {
      redoSteps=[];
      undoSteps.unshift(action);
    }
    action.do();
  }
  updateQueueDisplay();
};


let Reset=function()
{
  nodeI=0;
  undoSteps=[];
  redoSteps=[];
  document.getElementById('queue').innerHTML='-<br>';
  document.getElementById('nodes').innerHTML='';
}
```

```css
body{font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;}
#nodes{background:#ccc;padding:2px;min-height:68px;}
.node{width:64px;height:64px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;margin:2px;background:#cf9;cursor:pointer;}
.node.selected{box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #000 inset;}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="Act('create node',{})">Create node</button>
<button onclick="Undo()">Undo</button>
<button onclick="Redo()">Redo</button><button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>
(click a node to select it!)

<div id="queue">(action queue will show here)<br></div>

<div id="nodes"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any real JavaScript? See [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: working javascript example added!